# Where can I find a cannabinoids profile of hemp strains?

Tags: organic-chemistry

For my web article, I need to find out the content of individual cannabinoids in hemp strains, specifically for Kompolti, Carmagnola and Purple Haze. I mean the content of all the components, not just THC and CBD.

Do you know of any website that provides this information?
Thank you for answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because BiologySE (https://biology.stackexchange.com/) may represent a better audience than ChemSE.  The names you mention appear more like (possibly local) brand names (cf. https://industrialhempfarms.com/hemp-strains/), than systematic ones globally accepted (e.g., instead of the commoner's «ivy» the then more specific «Hedera helix L.»).  In addition, biologists (rather than chemists) were able e.g. to attenuate THC to practically zero and published this.